# Peak finding algorithm error

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Hello everybody could someone help me with my code

It is a code for peak finding ,if you are wondering what is peak finding

here you go

Given an array of integers. Find a peak element in it. An array element is peak if it is NOT smaller than its neighbors. For corner elements, we need to consider only one neighbor. For example, for input array {5, 10, 20, 15}, 20 is the only peak element. For input array {10, 20, 15, 2, 23, 90, 67}, there are two peak elements: 20 and 90. Note that we need to return any one peak element.

*My problem is that my code doesnt find a peak element if 
it is in first position in array or in last*

Here is my code it is fairly simple

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {



    int [] arr = {1,2,3,4,1,3,3,7,8,2,16};
    peakFinding(arr, 0,arr.length);

}


public static void peakFinding(int [] arr,int start ,int end){
    int mid  = (start+end)/2;



    if(arr[mid]<=arr[mid+1]){
            start = mid;
            end = arr.length;

            peakFinding(arr, start, end);
        }else if(arr[mid]<=arr[mid-1]){

            start = 0;
            end = mid-1;
            peakFinding(arr, start, end);
        }else{
            System.out.println("I have found peak "+arr[mid]);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you only need to find one element, and the choice is arbitrary, consider treating the edges as a special case. Before the call to `peakFinding` include code of the form

```
if (arr == null || arr.length < 2){
    /*do nothing, no elements*/
} else if (arr[0] >= arr[1]){
    /*first element is peak*/
} else if (arr[arr.length - 1] >= arr[arr.length - 2]){
    /*last element is peak*/
} else {
    /*call peakFinding*/
}
```

My first check also fixes a potential bug that you had.

Doing it this way preserves the clarity of the complicated parts of the program.

Finally, consider changing the return type of `peakFinding` to *return* the position of the element (`return mid;`), then the output message will be coded in one place.

Comment: Thank you very much  for replying so fast :)

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your question, I feel like the starting part of your peakFinding does not look very good, instead of

```
int mid  = (start+end)/2;
```

which might be problematic if start and end is too big and close to Integer.MAX_VALUE, please try

```
int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
```

Also if you add some code to validate the input (null check of the array, or start <= end something like that), it would be better.

Now let's talk about your algorithm, it is a binary search.

```
public static void peakFinding(int [] arr,int start ,int end){

while(start + 1 < end) {
    int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
    if(arr[mid] <= arr[mid+1]) {
        start = mid;
    } else if (arr[mid] <= arr[mid-1]) {
        end = mid;
    } else {
        System.out.println(arr[mid]);
        return;
    }
}

if(arr[start] > arr[end]) {
    System.out.println(arr[start]);
} else {
    System.out.println(arr[end]);
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Li :)

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not find all peaks.

If e.g. the condition `arr[mid] <= arr[mid + 1]` in the first `if` clause returns `true`, this means that a peak is searched only in the right part of the array. The left part of the array is no longer searched, although there could be a peak also in the left side of the array.

Comment: I need to find only one peak if there is one